# PHP : Get Multi Select Box value as comma separated value

Tags: php, html

Hi I have a multi select box as below

HTML

```
<form action="c3.php" method="post">
  <select name="ary[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Option 1" >Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="Option 5">Option 5</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I need to get the values selected by user as comma separated.
eg. if user selects Option1 and Option4   I need to read that as Option1,Option4
if he is selecting Option1 only .It should return as Option1 (no comma)

I have a code like this

```
PHP
foreach ($ary as $a){
    //echo $a;
    $com_values = implode(",", array_filter([$a])) ;
}
```

but the above php code is giving me only one value it is not giving me comma separated values /Any issues ?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? You override `$com_values` in each iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implode on the actual array, looping over the array is only going to give you the one value in the loop.

```
 $com_values = implode(",", $_POST["ary"]);
```

Should give you what you need.